# Capitalizing strings ignoring closed class words

Tags: macros, capitalization

I was just reviewing my "capitalization standards" for titles and such and was wondering if there's a macro to do the same thing I'm forced to do by hand nowadays. My personal rules (feel free to disagree/comment on them) are as follows:

1. the first letter (a number is a letter too for the sake of these rules) *always* gets capitalized,
2. *every* word gets capitalized individually,
3. the exception to the rule above (and *just* the rule above) are [closed class words](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Closed_class_word) such as prepositions and the like.

In other words: I'd like a capitalization command (like `\MakeUppercase`) that will capitalize every word *not* included in a list of words and that will *always* capitalize the first word of its argument.

Doable?

PS: one such "list" of closed class words (also known as "function words") can be found [here](http://www.sequencepublishing.com/academic.html).

Comment: Thinking about this, I had to up it. It's probably nice to do as conventions *do* vary, but this sounds like a neat idea for a package. Unless, that is, it already exists.

Comment: Doesn't bibTeX already do this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\capitalize}{>{\SplitList{~}}m}{
  \CapitalizeFirst#1\Capitalize\unskip
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\def\Sentinel{\Capitalize}
\def\CapitalizeFirst#1{\MakeUppercase#1 \Capitalize}
\def\Capitalize#1{%
  \def\next{#1}%
  \ifx\next\Sentinel
    \expandafter\unskip
  \else
    \CheckInList{#1}\space\expandafter\Capitalize
  \fi}
\def\CheckInList#1{%
  \ifcsname List@\detokenize{#1}\endcsname
    #1%
  \else
    \MakeUppercase#1%
  \fi}
\makeatletter
\def\AppendToList#1{%
  \@for\next:=#1\do
  {\expandafter\let\csname List@\detokenize\expandafter{\next}\endcsname\empty}}
\makeatother
\AppendToList{a,is,of}

\begin{document}
\capitalize{here is a list of words école}
\end{document}
```

Won't work with UTF-8 (unless XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX are used).

It won't work with UTF-8 in `pdflatex` because `\MakeUppercase` will apply only to the first byte of a possible two, three or four byte combination (for Western languages probably only two). For that to work one has to feed the whole block of bytes to `\MakeUppercase`.

To be clearer: when we say `\MakeUppercase`, LaTeX will uppercase the argument; in general the call is `\MakeUppercase{word}`; here we're saying instead `\MakeUppercase#1` (without braces), so only the first token (usually a character) will be uppercased; here's where it will fail with input such as `\'ecole`: the token passed to `\MakeUppercase` would be `\'`, which it doesn't know what to do. Using `école` (and a one byte encoding such as `latin1`), `\MakeUppercase` will process `é` and give the correct result.

With UTF-8 this would fail: what we *see* as `é` on our screen when writing a LaTeX document is actually *two bytes* (C3 and A9, for `é`) and again `\MakeUppercase` would be passed only the first one. So a more complex routine is necessary.

In order to have this work with `pdflatex` and UTF-8, the definition of `\CheckInList` and `\CapitalizeFirst` above can be changed into the following

```
\def\CapitalizeFirst#1{\expandafter\UC@next#1 \Capitalize}
\def\CheckInList#1{%
  \ifcsname List@\detokenize{#1}\endcsname
    #1%
  \else
    \expandafter\UC@next#1%
  \fi}
\def\UC@next#1{%
  \ifx#1\UTFviii@two@octets
     \expandafter\@firstoffour
  \else
    \ifx#1\UTFviii@three@octets
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@secondoffour
    \else
      \ifx#1\UTFviii@four@octets
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
        \@thirdoffour
      \else
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
        \expandafter\expandafter\@fourthoffour
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
  {\UC@two}{\UC@three}{\UC@four}{\MakeUppercase}#1}
\def\UC@two#1#2#3{\MakeUppercase{#1#2#3}}
\def\UC@three#1#2#3#4{\MakeUppercase{#1#2#3#4}}
\def\UC@four#1#2#3#4#5{\MakeUppercase{#1#2#3#4#5}}
\providecommand\@firstoffour[4]{#1}
\providecommand\@secondoffour[4]{#2}
\providecommand\@thirdoffour[4]{#3}
\providecommand\@fourthoffour[4]{#4}
```

However accent commands are not allowed (they aren't also in the other version).

---

## UPDATE

After a few years, here's a better implementation, thanks to new `expl3` features; it works for all engines.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{ifxetex}

\ifxetex
  \usepackage{fontspec}
\else
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\fi

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\capitalize}{>{\SplitList{~}}m}
 {
  \seq_clear:N \l_capitalize_words_seq
  \ProcessList{#1}{\CapitalizeFirst}
  \seq_use:Nn \l_capitalize_words_seq { ~ }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\CapitalizeFirst}{m}
 {
  \capitalize_word:n { #1 }
 }

\sys_if_engine_pdftex:TF
 {
  \cs_set_eq:Nc \capitalize_tl_set:Nn { protected@edef }
 }
 {
  \cs_set_eq:NN \capitalize_tl_set:Nn \tl_set:Nn
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \capitalize_word:n
 {
  \capitalize_tl_set:Nn \l_capitalize_word_tl { #1 }
  \seq_if_in:NfTF \g_capitalize_exceptions_seq { \tl_to_str:n { #1 } }
   % exception word
   { \seq_put_right:Nn \l_capitalize_words_seq { #1 } } % exception word
   % to be uppercased
   { \seq_put_right:Nx \l_capitalize_words_seq { \tl_mixed_case:V \l_capitalize_word_tl } }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_mixed_case:n { V }
\NewDocumentCommand{\AppendToList}{m}
 {
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \seq_gput_right:Nx \g_capitalize_exceptions_seq { \tl_to_str:n { ##1 } }
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_if_in:NnTF { Nf }
\seq_new:N \l_capitalize_words_seq
\seq_new:N \g_capitalize_exceptions_seq
\ExplSyntaxOff

\AppendToList{a,is,of,óf}

\begin{document}
X\capitalize{here is a list of words óf école}X
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'll test it in a moment. Care to explain why won't this work for UTF-8 under plain PDFLaTeX?

Comment: @mpr I added a short explanation; I'll think if I can provide a solution also for UTF-8

Comment: You, sir, you. :)

Comment: This works great (even for UTF-8), except that if I add the word the phrase begins with to the list of ignored words it doesn't get capitalized. The first word should _always_ get capitalized, irrespective of whether it belongs to the exceptions list or not.

Comment: @mpr I've changed both versions adding a macro `\CapitalizeFirst`

Comment: Works great!, could you please explain why won't it work with accent commands? :)

Comment: @egreg Regrettably, I could not join the first part and the second the part. Would you please kindly make the second part (`pdflatex` UTF8) one whole piece?

Comment: @blackened Better yet, a new implementation. In five years several things have changed.

Answer (score 12):

A ConTeXt solution:

You can use the command `\applytosplitstringwordspaced` for this:

```
\def\IgnoredWords
  {a,is,to,of,or,and}

\define[1]\CapitalizeWithIgnoreWord
  {\doifinsetelse{#1}\IgnoredWords{#1}{\Words{#1}}}

\def\CapitalizeWithIgnore
  {\applytosplitstringwordspaced\CapitalizeWithIgnoreWord}

\starttext
  \CapitalizeWithIgnore{This is some of my input or another and to the end.}
\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

The `\applytosplitstringwordspaced` command divides the input into words and applies each word to the macro `\CapitalizeWithIgnoreWord`, which takes one argument. Then I simply test, if the given word is a member of the word list and print it, or print it uppercased.

Comment: I edited your solution slightly to show how `\processowrd` is supposed to be used. I also changed `\Words` to `\Word`.

Answer (score 4):

The `titlecaps` package is newly introduced and demonstrated here: [Headings in uppercase](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45248/headings-in-uppercase/109368#109368).  It will take care of titling diacritical marks (e.g., umlauts, etc.) national symbols (e.g., oe) and is compatible with (i.e., can include in its argument) commands that change the font characteristics, such as `\textit{}`, `\scshape`, and `\footnotesize`.  Further, it allows for words to be designated as lower-cased, for example prepositions and conjunctions, which are to be screened out and not titled.  The presence of punctuation should not affect the ability of the package to either capitalize a word or detect it as a pre-designated lower-cased word.

Answer (score 3):

The [`mfirstuc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mfirstuc) package provides `\capitalisewords`. You can specify the exceptions with `\MFUnocap`. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mfirstuc}

\begin{document}
\capitalisewords{the cat sat on the mat.}

\MFUnocap{on}
\MFUnocap{the}
\capitalisewords{the cat sat on the mat.}
\end{document}
```

[image: The Cat Sat On The Mat. The Cat Sat on the Mat.]

The `mfirstuc-english` package (which automatically loads `mfirstuc`) provides some common exceptions:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mfirstuc-english}

\begin{document}
\capitalisewords{the cat sat on the mat.}
\end{document}
```

[image: The Cat Sat On the Mat.]

It doesn't include disputed words or words that may be ignored from case-changes only under certain circumstances. You can localise `\MFCnocap`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mfirstuc-english}

\begin{document}
{% scope
 \MFUnocap{on}
 \capitalisewords{the cat sat on the mat.}
}

\capitalisewords{the cat sat on the mat.}
\end{document}
```

[image: The Cat Sat on the Mat. The Cat Sat On the Mat.]

The switches `\MFUhyphenfalse` and `\MFUhyphentrue` determine whether or not to change the case of parts of hyphenated words. The default is `\MFUhyphenfalse`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mfirstuc}

\begin{document}
\capitalisewords{server-side includes}

\MFUhyphentrue
\capitalisewords{server-side includes}
\end{document}
```

[image: Server-side Includes Server-Side Includes]

Answer (score 1):

Using csplain you can implement this by a few lines of basic macros (they use only TeX primitives):

```
\def\capitalize#1{\capitA#1 {} }
\def\capitA#1 {\capitW#1 \capitB}
\def\capitB#1 {\ifx\relax#1\relax \else \space
   \isinlist\extrawords{ #1 }\iftrue #1\else \capitW#1 \fi
   \expandafter \capitB \fi
}
\def\capitW#1#2 {\uppercase{#1}#2}   
\def\isinlist#1#2#3{\begingroup \long\def\tmp##1#2##2\end{\def\tmp{##2}%
   \ifx\tmp\empty \endgroup \csname iffalse\expandafter\endcsname \else
                  \endgroup \csname iftrue\expandafter\endcsname \fi}%
   \expandafter\tmp#1\endlistsep#2\end
}

\def\extrawords{ a is of óf }

X\capitalize{here is a list of words óf école}X

\bye
```