# How to mimic BibTeX change.case$ built-in command?

Tags: bibtex, programming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Capitalizing strings ignoring closed class words](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34796/capitalizing-strings-ignoring-closed-class-words)

Neither `bibtex.exe` nor `bibtex8.exe` can handle unicoded database properly. Newrtheless  some peoplу (and me too) do use these routines to compile list of references. Example of such use provides `unicode-gost*.bst` styles from the package [GOST](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/gost). These styles avoid using `change.case$` primitive since it produces wrong output for Cyrillic alphabets.

Could someone direct me how to eleborate LaTeX command that would convert

```
"Some Paper Title" to "Some paper title"
```

and

```
"Some Paper Title on {LaTeX}" to "Some paper title on {LaTeX}"
```

?

Comment: You can look at [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34796/capitalizing-strings-ignoring-closed-class-words) that is very similar.

Answer (score 2):

Adapting [Capitalizing strings ignoring closed class words](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34796/capitalizing-strings-ignoring-closed-class-words) one can try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\uncapitalize}{>{\SplitList{~}}m}{
  \UncapitalizeFirst#1\Uncapitalize\unskip
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\def\Sentinel{\Uncapitalize}

\makeatletter
\def\Uncapitalize#1{%
  \def\next{#1}%
  \ifx\next\Sentinel
    \expandafter\unskip
  \else
    \CheckInList{#1}\space\expandafter\Uncapitalize
  \fi}
\def\UncapitalizeFirst#1{\expandafter\UC@next#1 \Uncapitalize}
\def\CheckInList#1{%
  \ifcsname List@\detokenize{#1}\endcsname
    #1%
  \else
    \expandafter\UC@next#1%
  \fi}
\def\UC@next#1{%
  \ifx#1\UTFviii@two@octets
     \expandafter\@firstoffour
  \else
    \ifx#1\UTFviii@three@octets
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@secondoffour
    \else
      \ifx#1\UTFviii@four@octets
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
        \@thirdoffour
      \else
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
        \expandafter\expandafter\@fourthoffour
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
  {\UC@two}{\UC@three}{\UC@four}{\MakeLowercase}#1}
\def\UC@two#1#2#3{\MakeLowercase{#1#2#3}}
\def\UC@three#1#2#3#4{\MakeLowercase{#1#2#3#4}}
\def\UC@four#1#2#3#4#5{\MakeLowercase{#1#2#3#4#5}}
\providecommand\@firstoffour[4]{#1}
\providecommand\@secondoffour[4]{#2}
\providecommand\@thirdoffour[4]{#3}
\providecommand\@fourthoffour[4]{#4}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\uncapitalize{Here is a List of Words École}

\selectlanguage{russian}

\uncapitalize{Москва Спасибо}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work with commands or braced groups.