# Headings in uppercase

Tags: sectioning, small-caps

I want to write the headings in `\scshape` family with the first character of each word in uppercase.

How can I do this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please register on this site, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 11):

The new `titlecaps` package can do this.  It's so new, in fact, it doesn't show up yet in a CTAN search, but can nonetheless be found there at http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlecaps

```
\documentclass{article}
\parindent 0em
\usepackage{titlecaps}
\begin{document}

\titlecap{\scshape this is a (test) of \LARGE titlecaps \normalsize on
\"uml\"auts}\normalfont

But if I don't like words like is of on and a being titled, I use
\verb|\Addlcwords| and try again:

\Addlcwords{is of on a}
\titlecap{\scshape this is a (test) of \LARGE titlecaps \normalsize on
\"uml\"auts}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can change the font of all headings using [sectsty](http://ctan.org/pkg/sectsty). Many fonts (including Computer Modern) don't have bold small caps, so you have to specify normal weight:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\mdseries\scshape}

\begin{document}
\section{A Section Header}
\end{document}
```

It's best to capitalize the headers manually. But if you really need an automatic solution, try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stringstrings}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\mdseries\scshape}

\let\oldsection=\section
\def\section#1{\oldsection{\capitalizewords{#1}}}
\let\oldsubsection=\subsection
\def\subsection#1{\oldsubsection{\capitalizewords{#1}}}
% and so on

\begin{document}
\section{a section header}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

@rdhs's first example can also be done with [titlesec](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec). It comes with the same caveat that bold small caps can not be used. In fact, adding `\bfseries` in the `<format>` section will clobber `\scshape`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\scshape\Large}
{\thesection}{1em}{}

\begin{document}
\section{A Section Header}
\end{document}
```