# Converting Text to Title Case

Tags: capitalization

is there a way to automatically format a text in title-case? Something like typing:

```
\somemagiccommand{the table, the ass and the stick}
```

which would yield:

```
The Table, the Ass and the Stick
```

I have searched the internet but have found nothing that would make this more efficient than doing the casing manually...

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: even a plain uppercase conversion is highly [non-trivial](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=casechange) in TeX. What you're looking for is going to be even more complex, as, in addition to those fundamental problems, TeX would have to have a way of knowing the difference between a »the« and an »Ass«, which as far as I know it doesn't. There's no such thing as an integrated word list (as hyphenation works without one). A poor man's solution would be to use an editor that, at least, can turn *every* first letter into uppercase. <alt> + <up> in WinEdt, for example.

Comment: Did you look at [Capitalizing strings ignoring closed class words](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34796/capitalizing-strings-ignoring-closed-class-words)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

\def\somemagiccommand#1{%
\let\tc@w\@empty
\protected@edef\tmp{\noexpand\tc@a#1\relax}\expandafter\tc@uc@\tmp}

\def\tc@a{\futurelet\tmp\tc@aa}

\def\tc@aa{%
\ifcat a\noexpand\tmp\expandafter\tc@ab
\else\expandafter\tc@ac\fi}

\def\tc@ab#1{\edef\tc@w{\tc@w#1}\tc@a}

\def\tc@ac{%
\csname tc@@\tc@w\endcsname\expandafter\tc@uc\tc@w
\let\tc@w\@empty
\ifx\tmp\@sptoken\let\next\tc@sp
\else\ifx\tmp\relax\let\next\relax
\else\let\next\tc@nxt
\fi\fi\next}

\def\tc@sp#1{ \tc@a#1}
\def\tc@nxt#1{#1\tc@a}

\def\tc@uc#1{\uppercase{#1}}
\def\tc@uc@#1#2{\uppercase{#1#2}}

\let\tc@@the\@gobbletwo
\let\tc@@and\@gobbletwo

\makeatother

\begin{document}


\somemagiccommand{the table, the ass and the stick}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What kind of voodoo magic is going here?  You have to be  hiding the words that are not to be upper cased somewhere, but I don't see it??

Comment: @PeterGrill `\somemagiccommand` was what was asked for. (The list of non uc-words is at the end of the code just before `\makeatother`)

Comment: Oh so obvious now..., Well at least where to add additional words that are not to be upper cased. So then you somehow check for the existence of `tc@@<xxx>` to keep `<xxx>` lower case. Good thing I didn't see this question earlier as I would have come up with a much more complicated solution... :-)

Comment: No I don't _check_ for that command, I _execute_ it and if it is defined it gobbles the uppercasing macro that follows.

Comment: @PeterGrill You would have _drawn_ the uppercase letters illuminated manuscript form, in TikZ.

Comment: Of course, `tikz` would have been involved, along with some unnatural tree colors. :-)  Seriously, it would have been involved as I would have used a `\foreach` loop.

Comment: Thanks, it is black magic to me, but it seems it does the trick :-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Is there any way to convert text to title case when base text is uppercase (or mixed case)? Your solution works for OP case, because all words are lowercase, but when they are uppercase it does not produce title case. I am wondering if only slight modification of your code do the trick or is something more complex needed to make it for for text that is uppercase.

Comment: @Rafal `\lowercase{\somemagiccommand{THE TABLE}}` probably works

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you for idea. Yes, it works when done in plain text, but when I try to insert macro/variable instead of text itself it stays uppercase. Example: ``\def \mytext{THE TABLE}`` and then ``\lowercase{\somemagiccommand{\mytext}}``. I tested also just ``\lowercase{\mytext}`` and it stays the same. While ``\MakeLowercase{\mytext}`` creates lowercase, ``\MakeLowercase{\somemagiccommand{\mytext}}`` throws errors on compilation.

Comment: @Rafal that's expected:-) But the site doesn't really support asking new questions on comments in old ones, feel free to ask a new question (you can refer to this one)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I know I should ask a new question :) But was just curious if small tweak of your solution could fix it. (In the meantime I decided to make all text in those macros lowercase, use ``\somemagiccommand`` on that lowercase text to make them title case and then use ``\uppercase`` wherever I need text in uppercase: it's easier this way.)

Answer (score 20):

You might want [`mfirstuc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mfirstuc) and its command `\capitalisewords{}`. In order to keep words like “the” small we must hide it from the mechanism by hiding the space before it. This is done by using `\space` instead of an actual space. Alternatively you can tell the parser with `\MFUnocap` which words to omit:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mfirstuc}

\begin{document}

\capitalisewords{the table,\space the ass\space and\space the stick}

\MFUnocap{the}\MFUnocap{and}

\capitalisewords{the table, the ass and the stick}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

The [`stringstrings`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/stringstrings) package has a `\capitalizetitle` macro that does what you want. You need to define words that are not capitalized.

Answer (score 4):

See [Headings in uppercase](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45248/headings-in-uppercase/109368#109368) for information about the introduction of the `titlecaps` package, designed for this task.

Answer (score 3):

for the sake of completeness, here's *semi-automatic* solution #3:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\begin{document}
Well {I} Have Searched the {ENTIRE} {I}nternet but Have Found Nothing\par
\MakeSentenceCase{Well {I} Have Searched the {ENTIRE} {I}nternet but Have Found Nothing}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP asked for.

Comment: that's why I pointed out it's semi-automatic. Like the one suggested by cgnieder -- which is structurally the same thing -- there's manual work to be done to indicate where to change or not to change case. Defining word lists containing exceptions is, of course, one of the better semi-automatic solutions -- but as I understand it, the OP is looking for something that just »knows« what to capitalize, thus sparing them manual work. InDesign can do that (IIRC), as can, apparently, [this thing here](http://individed.com/code/to-title-case/)