# Table of contents - sentence case on section headings

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, capitalization

I would like the section names in the TOC to be uniformly capatalised, either sentence case or not.

I achieve uniformity in section names now using `sectsty` and `\allsectionsfont{\normalfont\scshape}`

Is there anything similar for `\tableofcontents`?

This is my MWE,

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl} % A4 paper and 11pt font size

\usepackage{sectsty} % Allows customizing section commands
\allsectionsfont{\normalfont\scshape} % Make all sections centered, the default font and small caps

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Properly Formatted Section Name}
\section{Not so properly Formatted Section name}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your full intent, but you might be able to employ the `titlecaps` package to capitalize the first letter of each word.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45248/headings-in-uppercase/109368#109368

Answer (score 1):

No need of `sectsty` with `scrartcl`. Use

```
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\normalfont\scshape}
```

Code:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl} % A4 paper and 11pt font size

%\usepackage{sectsty} % Allows customizing section commands
%\allsectionsfont{\normalfont\scshape} % Make all sections centered, the default font and small caps

\addtokomafont{disposition}{\normalfont}               %% add here

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\normalfont\scshape}        %% add here
\section{Properly Formatted Section Name}
\section{Not so properly Formatted Section name}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would like to have the section name in the text as small caps, but in ToC, just normal sentence case (i.e 'Not So Properly Formatted Section Name')

Comment: @Ash See the edit. You have to use `\addtokomafont` twice.