# How to make every first letter of a word in uppercase?

Tags: capitalization

How to get every first letter of a word in uppercase and others are in lowercase only. For example, when typing "LATEX FOR DOCUMENT SETTING" or "latex for document setting" or "LateX foR Document SeTTing", LaTeX should produce "Latex For Document Setting" in every case.

Comment: Duplicates: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45248/headings-in-uppercase https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34796/capitalizing-strings-ignoring-closed-class-words https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103838/converting-text-to-title-case Easy solution: use the `titlecaps` package.

Comment: My problems will be solved if i can convert all the letters to lowercase , then giving input to \titlecap will do it. @TeXnician

Comment: `\usepackage{expl3}`, then you can do `\ExplSyntaxOn\str_lower_case:n {Your string here}\ExplSyntaxOff`.  The output of that function would be your argument.

Comment: where should i place this code in preamble or in document? @Texnician

Comment: As always in LaTeX, package use in preamble and the rest is usual document code.