# Title Case containing math

Tags: capitalization, titlecaps, mfirstuc

I have ben using the `\xcapitalisefmtwords` from the `mfirstuc` package (mentioned in the questions in the *References* section).  However, that fails if the content contain any math content.

Is there any easy way to disable the parsing of any math?

### References:

- [Capitalizing strings ignoring closed class words](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34796/4301)
- [Converting Text to Title Case](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/103838/4301)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{mfirstuc}
\newcommand{\TitleCase}[1]{\xcapitalisefmtwords{#1}}%

\begin{document}
    \TitleCase{hello world}

    %\MFUnocap{$\mathbb{C}$}%
    \TitleCase{hello $\mathbb{C}$ world}%  <-- How do I get this to work

    Desired Output: Hello $\mathbb{C}$ World
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\TitleCase{hello\ \ensuremath{\mathbb{C}} world}` works for me.

Comment: @ferahfeza: Thanks. I have tried to forget about `\ensuremath` since someone very knowledgable on this site scolded :-) me for it many years ago!!

Comment: Your welcome :-). Did he/she say we shouldn't use the `ensuremath` command?

Comment: @ferahfeza: See [When not to use \ensuremath for math macro?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34830/4301).  You should consider posting an answer. Not sure if there are any other lurking issues with your solution, but seems to work fine. I came up with a more of  _hack_ solution, but will hold of posting that until later.

Comment: Thank you. I am not a TeXpert, so I cannot explain the validity of the solution and investigate conflicts, if there is.

Comment: As of v 2.08 of mfirstuc, this seems to be handled automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{mfirstuc}
\newcommand{\TitleCase}[1]{\xcapitalisefmtwords{#1}}%

\protected\def\Cb{$\mathbb{C}$}
\begin{document}
    \TitleCase{hello world}

    %\MFUnocap{$\mathbb{C}$}%
    \TitleCase{hello {\Cb} world}%  <-- How do I get this to work

    Desired Output: Hello $\mathbb{C}$ World
\end{document}
```

---

Original image that Barbara asked about

[image]

Comment: Two questions on this solution - is `\protected` necessary and is there a reason to use `{\Cb}` rather than, say `\Cb\ ` ?

Comment: @John I know nothing about the package I just guessed, but `\Cb\  world` does not result in a capital W, whether by design or bug I can not say, `{\Cb} world` does result in W

Comment: Ah ... I overlooked the `w` !  Thanks.

Comment: Why is the `\mathbb{C}` smaller than the surrounding uppercase letters?

Comment: @barbarabeeton that's an interesting question